# Is there some kind of VBO/VAO in Canvas 2D or p5.js?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, webgl, p5.js

I'm working on a project which uses the marching squares algorithm. It outputs many polygons and this causes a performance drop when I draw it via the conventional p5.js way. I know from OpenGL and WebGL that there is VBO/VAO which let you draw much much quicker. Is there similar functionality in p5.js or canvas 2d? Or is there a better solution like direct use of WebGL?

I have a 1000x1000 voxel grid which generates a poly array through the marching squares algorithm.
I draw currently three of these polygon lists per frame.
I use p5.js to draw it every frame. One frame takes more than 500ms to draw.
To reduce it, I think the best solution would be to use some kind of VBO/VAO with p5.js or canvas 2d.

This the code to draw one polygon list with p5.js:

```js
polys.forEach(function(poly : number[][]) {
  g.beginShape();
  poly.forEach(function(vert : number[]) {
    var x = vert[0];
    var y = vert[1];
    g.vertex(x, y);
  });
  g.endShape();
});
```

I need to reduce the drawing time drastically to something like 50ms o less.

Comment: were you able to find a vbo in p5js or similar implementation? I am looking for the same.